# Dynamic regex to match a string(s) based on a number of characters but not splitting a string

Tags: regex, xml, xslt

Please help me to solve my problem. I need to create a dynamic regex to match a string and split them by a number of characters but should not split any word. the number of characters could be 10 or 12 or 15.
I am using xslt as my core and will use regex for this scenario only. Because as far as I know xslt cannot do this.

I have been doing regex testing before I incorporate it in my xslt code.

my xslt code is:

```
<xsl:variable name="NumOfChar" select="[NumOfCol]"/>

<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$NumOfCol = 10">
    <xsl:value-of select="[regex here]"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="$NumOfCol = 15">
    <xsl:value-of select="[regex here]"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="[regex here]"/>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

I tried many regex but I am currently focussed on this expression:

\b.{1,10}

but the problem is it will not catch the word with 10 or more characters. It will just split.

INPUT: (10 chars)

```
<p>
    <text>The latest international news</text>
</p>
```

OUTPUT: (10 chars)

```
<p>
    <text>The latest</text>
    <text>international</text>
    <text>news</text>
</p>
```

INPUT: (15 chars)

```
<p>
    <text>Comprehensive up-to-date news coverage</text>
</p>
```

OUTPUT: (15 chars)

```
<p>
    <text>Comprehensive</text>
    <text>up-to-date news</text>
    <text>coverage</text>
</p>
```

Comment: Its a little unclear what exactly you are asking I'm afraid. Could you show the actual and desired output for the 10 and 15 char examples. Thanks

Comment: What is the `<xsl:variable name="NumOfChar" select="[NumOfCol]"/>` supposed to represent? I don't think the `[NumOfCol]` will compile. Or which XSLT version and which XSLT processor do you use?

Comment: @Damo the desired output were posted above. OUTPUT: (10 chars) and OUTPUT: (15 chars)

Comment: @MartinHonnen the number of columns will be pulled from the xml input. the variable NumOfChar will be determined from tag on the input xml. I am using XSLT 2.0 and I am using editix for the testing.

Comment: sorry for the confussion. let's say I have to split the sentence for every 10 characters. using the source:

The latest international news

the expected output is:

The latest\ninternational\nnews

the goals is to insert a linebreaks in every 10characters but should not split any word. many thanks!

Comment: more complex input and output:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<header>
 <text>Dec. 13. As always for a presidential inaugural, security and surveillance were extremely tight in Washington DC, last January. But as George W. Bush prepared to take the oath of office, security planners installed an extra layer of protection: a prototype software system to detect a biological attack.</text>
</header>

Comment: EXPECTED OUTPUT: (linebreaks)
Dec. 13.\nAs always\nfor a\npresidential\ninaugural,\nsecurity\nand\nsurveillance\nwere\nextremely\ntight in\nWashington\n DC, last\nJanuary.\nBut as\nGeorge W.\nBush\nprepared\nto
take\nthe oath\nof office,\nsecurity\nplanners\ninstalled\nan extra\nlayer of\nprotection\na\nprototype\nsoftware\nsystem\nto detect\na\nbiological\nattack.

Comment: XSLT 2 and later has the `xsl:analyze-string` element you can use with regular expressions to break up strings, but the regular expression language in XSLT/XPath doesn't support the `\b` word boundary at all. That begs the question whether you use Saxon 9 in a version where you can switch to the Java regular expression which I think supports `\b`. Please edit your question and insert any code thrown into comments there as well-formatted code samples.

Comment: OR EXPECTED OUTPUT: (enclosed in text tag)
<header>
  <text>Dec. 13.</text><text>As always</text><text>for a</text><text>presidential</text><text>inaugural,</text><text>security</text><text>and</text><text>surveillance</text><text>were</text><text>extremely</text><text>tight in</text><text>Washington</text><text> DC, last</text><text>January.</text><text>But as</text><text>George W.</text><text>Bush</text><text>prepared</text><text>to take</text><text>the oath</text><text>of office,</text><text>security</text><text>planners</text><text>installed</text>...too many characters

Comment: @MartinHonnen yes will use saxon9 soon. I definitely need a regex to break up string without splitting any word but I can't solve my problem.

Comment: Maybe try to update your question with the clarification and examples, instead of leaving them in the comments. That would make the question a whole lot clearer, and people would not have to read all the comments to understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know next to nothing about xslt, but the following regex looks like what you need.

`\b.{1,10}\b|\b\S+\b` which you can test [here](https://regex101.com/r/9YINFN/1)

It splits into groups of 10 characters except for long words.

EDIT

As per more conversations and a change to the spec the following regex using look behind and look ahead rather than word boundaries will allow special characters to be included in the match as per requirements.

`((?<=\s)|^).{1,10}((?<=\s)|$)|((?<=\s)|^)\S+((?=\s)|$)`
[demo here](https://regex101.com/r/9YINFN/3)

Comment: Another favor @Damo. If this expression requires to be dynamic, meaning the groupings could be 10 chars or 15 chars or 20 chars? Many Thanks again

Comment: Your welcome. I'm afraid i have no idea how you would pass in a variable from your xslt template into the regex. Maybe this calls for a new question to stack overflow?

Comment: What if the expression needs to be dynamic. Meaning the groupings could be 10 chars or 15 chars or 20 chars? @Damo

Comment: @hulikabalbon : <xsl:call-template> should work with the chars length as parameter

Comment: @Damo What are the alternative syntax for \b word boundary? Because it is not supported by XSLT 2.0 Saxon 9. :(

Comment: Maybe you could use look ahead/look behind syntax. Does XSLT 2.0 Saxon 9 support those features?

Comment: Sorry @Mark i didn't follow your comment. are you saying that when the input is ```Realized gain (loss) Change in unrealized appreciation (depreciation)``` you don't get the output that you expect?

Comment: @Damo Seems there is a little lapse on the output when I used this input:

Realized gain (loss)
Change in unrealized appreciation (depreciation)

Actual output groupings would be like this:
Realized<space>
gain (loss
Change in<space>
unrealized
<space>    -->this shouldn't be catched as it doesn't match whitespace alone.
appreciation
<space>(
depreciation

*the closing parenthesis were missing.

Appreciate your help on this again. Thank You! :)

Comment: The problem is the definition of the word boundary \b it is the boundary between a character matched by \w and a character not matched by \w (\w is the same as [a-zA-Z0-9_]) am i correct in saying you want the round braces to be included in the definition of a word? the logical next question is what about square brackets or curlies or single/double quotes, question marks and the like. you need to define the conditions you care about and then look for a generic solution. I cant promise a solution to this but will have a think.

Comment: the current problems that I have in my input are:
1. closing parenthesis should be catched;
2. space between two 10/10+ characters should not be catched;
3. special characters attached to a word and word after a specail character should be catched.

Thanks @Damo. you're the best :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use this template structure to split the string:

Though, it's XSLT 1.0 style and also it doesn't check the splitted string is a word or not.

You can share more detail about your source in order to integrate regex with xslt and get more accurate result

```
<xsl:call-template name="splitSequence">
    <xsl:with-param name="input" select="your xpath to grab the string"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="length" select="'15'"/>
</xsl:call-template>

<xsl:template name="splitSequence">
    <xsl:param name="input" />
    <xsl:param name="length" />
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($input,1,$length)" /><xsl:value-of select="$newLine" />
    <xsl:if test="substring($input,$length+1)">
        <xsl:call-template name="splitSequence">
            <xsl:with-param name="input" select="substring($input,$length+1)" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This will only catch the first 15 characters.

Comment: Right. You need to call the template with the required parameter's value in your <xsl:choose> / <xsl:when> given in the question.

Comment: but this will split a word :(